Validate Laravel Database Entry on Request Only For Specific Values
I have my dropdown with options populated from the database. Along with I have an option named other with value -1
Below is the html output for better understanding

The Other is hardcoded.
I have created a request validation file and code as below.
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Requests\Profiles\Form;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    class BasicRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         */
        public function authorize(): bool
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
         */
        public function rules(): array
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|min:3|max:30',
                'relation' => 'required'
            ];
        }
    }

Now, how do I write a validation condition to check only for options that are not equal to -1 are available in the database.
Lets say if I use exists:relations,name works fine for myself...nephew but will throw error for -1. I don't want to add other into the db table.

A simple way to handle this would be to make the rules dynamic. You can add the exists rule when the value is not -1.
So your form validation rules could look like
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:30',
        'relation' => [
            'required',
            $this->relation != -1 ? 'exists:relations,name' : Rule::in([-1])
        ],
    ];
}

Make sure to customise the Validation Message for the Rule::in.
You could alternatively create a custom Validation Rule for this... but that seems overkill for such a simple scenario.

Thanks. It worked. Just for future reference, we need to include this line  "use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;"
